# 16s time delay until the bluetooth disconnected request is recognized

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working with a bluetooth device (the IOIO developer board).

I want to listen, when my device is disconnected. It is working ok with the code above, but it is not recognized instantaneously. When I power off my bluetooth developer board, I have to wait ~16s until my Android recognized that the connection was lost.

Does anybody know why? I heard it should be a internal Android limitation, that the connection is not checked so often?
Does anybody know how to write a thread which "pings" the bluetooth device if it is still there? I think it is very similar to the Android BluetoothChat example, but I couldn't fixed it on my own.

Thanks.

Felix

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
```

}

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {            
          String action = intent.getAction();
          BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

         if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
              //Device is about to disconnect
              Toast.makeText(context,"The device is about to disconnect" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
              //Device has disconnected
              Toast.makeText(context,"Device has disconnected" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }           
       } 
   };
```

Comment: I'm looking to decrease the time between OS disconnect and the ACTION_ACL* broadcasts.  Did you learn anything more?  Have you ever received a BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED event?

Comment: The same issue appeared to me with bluetooth-le devices as well :(